# ggplot 2 barplot with a diverging colour palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have this barplot in R (created with `ggplot2`)
[image]

I need to have it like this:

[image]

I tried to use RColorBrewer package, but it didn't work since the maximum amount of colours in the coresponding palette is 11. Any ideas?

```
pal <- brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn")
ggplot(data = bm_mod, aes(x = bm_mod$country, y = bm_mod$V)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = pal, fill = pal) + coord_flip() + 
  labs(y="Under/over valuation in %", x="")
```

Here is the data: [link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8317296/bm_mod.csv.html)

Update:
I tried it again with this code:

```
ggplot(data = bm_mod, aes(x = country, y = V)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = country, show_guide = FALSE) + 
  coord_flip() + scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"))(nrow(bm_mod))) +
  labs(y="Under/over valuation in %", x="")
```

However the output looks pretty weird. Is it a problem with the brewer or another mistake?

[image]

Comment: It will be very difficult to help unless you provide a reproducible example that we can run ourselves.

Comment: Just a tip - you don't need to put `bd_mod$` in your aesthetics. You can just say something like `ggplot(data = bm_mod, aes(x = country, y = V))`

Comment: @joran I added the dataset.

Comment: @Henrik Oh sry. Changed that but stille have the same result.

Comment: Put `fill = V` in the `aes` argument.

Comment: @Henrik This changes the color order a bit but still the same colors as in my last picture above. Furthermore I got these warnings: `Warning messages:
1: Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0 
2: In col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : col2rgb(0) is deprecated`

Comment: `country` is a discrete variable, and if you map `fill` to it then the palette used in Joran's example works fine. On the other hand, if you choose to fill the bars according to their continuous values `V`, which may seem more natural, you need a continuous scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few points:

As Nick noted, you should not be using `bd_mod$` to refer to variables inside of `aes()`. The whole point of specifying `data = bm_mod` is that is frees you from having to type `bm_mod$` over and over again.

Secondly, your attempt at setting `fill = pal` is somewhat confused. Specifying an aesthetic outside of `aes()` means you are *setting* it to a specific value, so that should only be done with a *single* value, e.g. `fill = "blue"`.

What you really want is a different fill for each x value, so you should be *mapping* fill to `country` and then setting the color scheme in `scale_fill_manual`.

When you ask questions like these, you should always provide a reproducible example. In this case, that would have been very easy, something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters,y = runif(26))

ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = x),stat = "identity",show_guide = FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlGn"))(26))
```

I've used `colorRampPalette` to interpolate the colors in the brewer palette you would like to use.

Comment: Thx. I tried and it worked partially. The colors actually don't look like I need to have it. I updated my post above.

Comment: @SWR It didn't work because you still don't understand the difference between _mapping_ and _setting_ aesthetics. You are still _setting_ fill. You need to _map_ it, inside of `aes()`. Notice how my code says `aes(fill = x)`. Is your `fill = country` inside of `aes()`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with fake data. You need to specify `fill=V` in the aesthetics, as Henrik pointed out. And then you need a `scale_fill_XXXX` piece to specify which color scale you want to use.

```
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
fake.data = data.frame(country = LETTERS, V = runif(26, -40, 40))
fake.data$country = factor(LETTERS, LETTERS[order(fake.data$V)]) # reorder factors

ggplot(data = fake.data, aes(x = country, y = V, fill = V)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="green") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y="Under/over valuation in %", x="")
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Colored Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0):

Would be enough to define 11 intervals and assign colors to them? Try this:

```
intervals <- cut(bm_mod$V, 11)
ggplot(data=bm_mod, aes(x=country, y=V)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour=pal[intervals], fill=pal[intervals]) +
        coord_flip() + labs(y="Under/over valuation in %", x="")
```